# Google drive in WSL

Tags: windows-10, command-line, wsl2, google-drive-for-desktop

I have google drive `G:\` in my `Windows 10`. Trying to open it in `WSL Ubuntu` with command:

```
cd /mnt/g
```

Command works fine, but `ls` command shows nothing there. Why?

Comment: Try `sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g`

Comment: Should none of these other suggestions work, it is possible that that drive doesn't actually exist.  It might be a virtual representation provided by explorer.exe through a shell extension.  I don't know diddly about google drive but a LOT about how the explorer does what it does.  If the shell extension can pass through to WSL2.. someone at Microsoft deserves a free lunch.

Answer (score 7):

This problem apparently appeared in WSL2.

Use the command :

```
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

The first time you do it, run `sudo mkdir /mnt/g` first.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is it there a way to do this automatically at startup, without asking for a password?

Answer (score 0):

I sync all of GDrive to my Win11 device.  Then, on Win11/WSL2, from bash terminal:

```bash
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/your-windows-username-here/"My Drive" ~/gdrive
```